# Fetching wikidata properties from an entity discovered by property value

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I'm attempting to find location data by the url of an entity. This query returns zero results, but if I replace the P856 clause with `?item wdt:* wd:Q48340 .` it works just fine.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemDescription ?locationLabel ?cityLabel ?postalCodeLabel ?countryLabel ?countryISOCodeLabel ?coordinates ?coordinatesLabel WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P856 "https://www.cnn.com/" .
  OPTIONAL {  }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P276 ?address. }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P159 ?headquarters. }
  BIND(COALESCE(?address, ?headquarters) AS ?location)
  OPTIONAL { ?location wdt:P131 ?city. }
  OPTIONAL { ?location wdt:P281 ?postalCode. }
  OPTIONAL { ?location wdt:P17 ?country. }
  OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P297 ?countryISOCode. }
  OPTIONAL { ?location wdt:P625 ?coordinates. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the entity [CNN](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q48340) (`Q48340`), the `wdt:P856` value is an IRI, not a string.

```
?item wdt:P856 <https://www.cnn.com/> .
```